# Slick JS: Continuous slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've been testing the [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) carousel which results to be very useful.

For now, it calculates image widths and positions by taking account the options `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` (and other properties as well).

What I would like to know, is it a way to show all the slides as a fixed width and height carousel?  Without padding and without considering `slidesToShow` so it looks like a continuous **photographic film**? This way the ammount of slides that would appear would only depend on the width of the div wrapper size.

Somehow I've been playing with the inner div's width property (setting it to `auto !important`), but the ammount to scroll is calculated using the original values.

PD: Please, don't address the fact that elements will go to the next line as the browser gets shrinked, as we could use the responsive property to solve this.